# pod 'ReadMoreTextView' is not working. Swift 2.3 How to add ReadMore Button in TextView?

Tags: ios, swift, textview, uitextview

[Here I used pod url](https://github.com/ilyapuchka/ReadMoreTextView)

**My code is that in picture:**

[image]

When I add that *read more text* with this code I can not see anything in view. So basicly it doesn't working. So how I can make my **textview** with ***Read More*** tag. Is there any pod like this or do you have any solution for this ? I'm using `Swift 2.3`

Comment: You are setting the text for `ReadMoreTextView` in the `didSet` of the `text` variable in your `AkisTextView` class. Unless you provide a value to `text` in a `AkisTextView` class instance, you will not see anything appear

Comment: Can you paste here in a comment what is the text you are setting and what you expect to see?

Comment: I'm setting which value comes from api is '' Deneme '' but I don't see anything in my view, So when I give that view any value by myself still can't see anything. I think problem is on addsubview function. @indyfromoz

Comment: @OkanYücel Try my solution i am sure the problem is with the frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am Pretty Sure The problem is because you haven't assign frame to the TextView Try by adding frame

```
let textView:ReadMoreTextView = ReadMoreTextView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 150))
        textView.text = "sadkhfasdjfkasdklf lskadj fklsad jflskad jflk asdlfkjsaldk fjlsdakjflasdjlfkjsadlkfjlsakdjf ldsjflj lkdsjflaksdflkj dfjlkdsjflkj lkdjfalkjflsdk jfklsdjflksdjflkdsjlkf salkf"
        textView.maximumNumberOfLines = 4
        textView.shouldTrim = true
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        textView.attributedReadLessText = NSAttributedString(string:"Read Less")
        textView.attributedReadMoreText = NSAttributedString(string:"ReadMore")
        textView.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(textView)
```